# Is there a way to restrict gadgetfs to Full Speed?

Tags: linux, usb, driver

I have two USB devices (host and device) that both support high speed.  I am trying to emulate a legacy device on gadgetfs which is full speed.  The host device unfortunately complains that there is something odd when it connects to the high speed device.  I cannot change anything on the host.  my device is a Raspberry Pi zero W.

I can not find any way to restrict the gadgetfs device to connect (negotiate?) as a full speed device.  Short term I am using a usb 1.1 hub to sovle the problem. Long term this is not a viable solution.

The only reference I have found for this is in [Limit USB gadget driver speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704906/limit-usb-gadget-driver-speed), and  I would prefer not to have go into the kernel and modify the drivers.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Maybe I did not elaborate the details enough, this is a programming issue.  I am writing a linux userspace gadgetfs driver to emulate the device and am trying to limit the the gadgetfs interface to HS.  The gadgetfs API has very limited documentations.  I can not find any references as to how to limit gadgetfs connections speeds.  I was hoping there was a way to do this with gadgetfs, and if not some other alternative.

Comment: Do you have a git repository? I would be glad to help if I could see the code you used.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without modifying the drivers.  It has not been as big an issue as I thought it would be so I have been able to live with the problem.  For reference I was originally trying to get it to work with USBProxy so that if the device was a full speed device after going through USBYproxy is would show as a full speed device to the host rather than a high speed device.

Comment: Just wondering, how did you get GadgetFS to work on the raspi zero? I have been trying to turn the Raspi Zero W into an HID device and I can't even create the device. I have been using https://github.com/ueno/libusb-gadget but it keeps erroring. I guess, I would like to see your code because you seem to have solved this.

Comment: Please, from one dev to another, I cannot seem to get this to work!!!

Comment: I never used libusb-gadget.  I would start with the example @ http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/usb.c.  The code I used is from the USBProxy project https://github.com/usb-tools/USBProxy-legacy/blob/master/src/Plugins/Hosts/HostProxy_GadgetFS.cpp or my branch https://github.com/mweal-ed/USBProxy/blob/master/src/Plugins/Hosts/HostProxy_GadgetFS.cpp